# Interesting overriding scenario

Tags: java, overriding

Suppose we have two overridden versions of a method.

One accepts `int` as argument like `someMethod(int i)`.

Other accepts `Long` as arguments like `someMethod(Long i)`.

If we pass `float` as argument i.e. `someMethod(float Numeber)` which one will be called?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't compile unless you do a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, posted a totally incorrect test..

It won't compile as stated before, because in both cases (`int` or `long`) you will loose precision of the `float` number (which has decimals).

The method called will depend on your cast.